# Getting `Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.` even after updating the Version to latest

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to build flutter apk by running

```
flutter build apk
```

However i'm getting the following error on the console:

```
 Your project requires a    ││ newer version of the Kotlin    ││ Gradle plugin.                 ││ Find the latest version on     ││ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/re ││ leases.html#release-details,   ││ then update                    ││ C:\Users\USER\Documents\Flutte ││ rSignUp\signuppage\android\bui ││ ld.gradle:                     ││ ext.kotlin_version =           ││ '<latest-version>'
```

This is my build.gradle (root project) configuration

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20' 
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"    
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As you can see above the `ext.kotlin_version` is set to the latest which is 1.8.20 however the error is still being thrown.

What I've tried:

- Run flutter upgrade
- Run flutter clean
- Run flutter pub upgrade

Flutter version: 3.7.11

It still doesn't seem to fix the issue.

AndroidManifest.xml configuration:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.signuppage">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
        android:label="AppName"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`build.gradle` (/android/app/build.gralde) configuration:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {

    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    namespace "com.example.signuppage"

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.signuppage"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
}
```

Other information:

OS: Windows 10

Text Editor: Visual Studio Code

Comment: change  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'

Comment: @JasminSojitra I tried your solution and I'm getting the following error after running flutter build apk on the console `Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:` I'm not sure what this mean but several google searching suggested that i should add namespace 'com.example.namespace' (I replaced the namespace name with my own project) on `build.gralde` but it still does not work or maybe I placed the `namespace 'com.example.namespace` in the wrong place? Where should i place it? See my updated question to see my build.gradle configuration.

Comment: Not in One but in other file also need to change bundle name check this https://medium.com/@skyblazar.cc/how-to-change-the-package-name-of-your-flutter-app-4529e6e6e6fc

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have the same now